# How to mix local and override members in tuple assignment

Tags: scala, overriding, traits

I have a timing function:

```
def time[R](code: => R, t: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()) = 
  (code,  System.currentTimeMillis() - t )
```

It returns a tuple of the return value of the code, and the time that code took to execute.

I have a trait of various things I'm timing across multiple objects:

```
trait TimingStats {
  var step1Time, step2Time, step3Time : Long
}
```

I have an object doing things that I am timing:

```
class Process extends TimingStats {
  var (step1Result, step1Time) = time(Thread.sleep(1000))
  var (step2Result, step2Time) = time(Thread.sleep(2000))
  var (step3Result, step3Time) = time(Thread.sleep(3000))
}
```

(Of course, the `Thread.sleep` is actually useful code, not just a sleep directive)

But, this doesn't work, with a compiler fail of "variable step1Time needs `override' modifier".

How should I actually be trying to do this?

PS - Larger context is that I'm then reporting these stats to Prometheus as part of application monitoring, in case you were going to suggest various profiling tools instead.

Comment: You can't override a `val` with a `var`. Why do you want step results and step times to be mutable?

Comment: Updated. Different compilation problem when they match. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, the mutability isn't necessary, but a side-effect of something else I'm trying to do.

Comment: The updated code compiles and runs for me.

Comment: Good to know, must be some difference between my sample here and what I'm actually doing. Hmm.

Comment: @Narfanator It is a good idea to run example code yourself so that you are sure that it demonstrates the same problem that you are seeing in your real code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the tuples, the problem is that you can't override an immutable value with a mutable value. Replace the `var` with `val` and it will compile.

Comment: Fixed. Different issue.